# How to embed Power BI report template into React

Tags: reactjs, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I was trying to embed the **Power BI report template** into React first time and connect the [PostgreSQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PostgreSQL) database with it.

I have found the way to embed Power BI report, but there isn't any information available for the report templates. How can I import/ embed the Power BI report template in React?

Comment: It is not possible. To embed a resource it must be published to the service and you cannot publish a template. Report templates are just files, which creates a new report when you open them.

Comment: That report should get created in power BI itself? or can we create outside the power BI

Comment: Usually the reports are created in [Power BI Desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/fundamentals/desktop-getting-started), but then can be designed in [Power BI service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/fundamentals/service-get-started) too. There are no other tools (3rd party tools) to create Power BI reports, if this is what you mean by "outside the Power BI".

Comment: @AndreyNikolov Can we change the dataSource Type for the existing pbix file. Ex. we need to change the datasource from SQL to postgres using RestAPI, is that possible?

Comment: No, changing the type of the data source is a change of the M code of the report, thus it is not possible through the API.